# Which affix appends to the verb in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, separable-verb

Looking at this sentence, from a Schopenhauer's "Über die Weiber", I'm not able to identify which of the affixes belongs to the separable verb. See:

> Besser, als Schiller's wohlüberlegtes, mittelst der Antithese und des Kontrastes wirkendes Gedicht, »Würde der Frauen«, ***sprechen***, meiner Meinung **nach**, diese wenigen Worte Jouy's das wahre Lob der Weiber **aus**: *sans les femmes, le commencement de notre vie seroit privé de secours, le milieu de plaisirs, et la fin de consolation.*

Is it *nachsprechen* or *aussprechen*? 
For me it seems like both make sense, but I'm inclined to believe *aus* attaches to *sprechen*, but if that's the case, why does he uses the word *nach* in the sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Meiner Meinung nach" means "in my opinion". One would expect "nach meiner Meinung", but the way it is worded is traditional. It also changes the word order in the rest of the sentence a little: "Meiner Meinung nach sprechen diese wenigen Worte Joeys das wahre Lob der Weiber aus".

The verb is "aussprechen": [diese wenigen Worte Jouys] sprechen [das wahre Lob der Weiber] aus.

Answer (score 1):

*Better than Schiller's well-considered, through means of antithesis and contrast effective poem, "Dignity of Women", these few words Jouy's, are speaking, in my opinion, out the true praise of women.*

I think this may come the closest to a literal translation while keeping most of the original sentence structure and still forming a valid English sentence.